# How to call a Form from another project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have two WinForm projects(A,B) in one solution.

A project is VB.Net2

B project is C#.Net4

They both have Form.

The A project is set as startup project and has START button.
When I press the button I have to activate Form from the B project.

Any Idea how can Implement it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is B project already running before the button click?

Comment: No,B have to run after i press START button

Comment: Use `Process.Start` to activate B

Answer (score 7):

You first need to get a reference from project A to project B. To do so, right-click project A, select `Add Reference`, select tab `Projects`, and double-click project B.

Now you'll be able to reference the form in project B in project A:

`Namespace.FormName.Show()`

Comment: it's a problem i use two diffrent versions of .net

Comment: @Michael, can you create a third project that loads both project A and B?

Comment: I missed that part, sorry. IIRC, it should be possible to reference the compiled DLL of project B instead of the project itself to make things work. Never tried it though.

Answer (score 6):

1. In your Project A add a reference to Project B (right-click on the project, Add Reference..., click on Projects tab and add Project B).
2. In your Project A add Imports ProjectBNamespace
3. Create a variable of type ProjectBClassName, eg. `Dim sample As New SampleForm()`, in your button click event handler
4. Inside this event handler call `sample.Show()` or `sample.ShowDialog()`. The first option will open a modeless dialog box, while the other one is a modal dialog box.